# Unsetting formatter's third party settings

Tags: 8

We have this hook [hook_field_formatter_third_party_settings_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field_ui%21field_ui.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_third_party_settings_form/8.2.x) that allows us to set third party settings in formatter settings form. But what would be the best way of **unsetting** them if we are changing formatter to one that doesn't support our setting?

Comment: By "unsetting" do you mean you want to remove some other setting that you're not creating in the hook? Or do you mean you want to selectively pick which field formatter your setting applies to?

Comment: @ShawnConn By unsetting I mean just that - I can set a setting, but after changing formatter to one that doesn't support this setting - it shouldn't be left in configuration anywhere, and just be unset. So after I will restore the formatter, that used it, it will have again its default value, and not the one I previously set.